# Script only picking up first 3 letter

Tags: php

Im using the following script in conjunction with a autocomplete script to search my db. If I put in the letter a for example it is finding all the ID's with an a. I want to change it so by typing the letter a it will only bring up data in the id field that begings with the letter a.

```
<?php
require('json.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id,dsc FROM module WHERE id LIKE '%%%s%%'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']));
$result = mysql_query($sql)
  or die(mysql_error());
$all = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $all[] = array('value'=>$row[1],'label'=>$row[1]);
print json_encode($all);
?>
```

Comment: check out pattern matching http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: To confirm - your trying to find things that begin with the letters you type rather than find things with the lettters anywhere within the `id` field ?

Comment: Yes letters that I type, by typing the letter a it will noly bring up data in the id field that begings with the letter a. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

(If I understand your question correctly)

You need to change your `LIKE` query :

```
%a%
```

finds everything with `a` anywhere in the `id` field ...

```
a%
```

finds everything with `a` at the start of the `id` field ...

[Docs for `LIKE` are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: Yes letters that I type, by typing the letter a it will noly bring up data in the id field that begings with the letter a. Thanks